# Is thunk action synchronous?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, async-await, redux-thunk

are functions you dispatch with thunk middleware synchronous by default? I mean, I know that you can make these functions async and for example dispatch redux actions after some awaits, but is dispatched function (which gets dispatch as argument) call sync or async by default?  (if you won't make it async explicitly)

For example

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
dispatch(randomCasualSyncFunction());
doStuffAfterRandomCasualSyncFunctionReturns();
```

will doStuffAfterRandomCasualSyncFunctionReturns() get called after randomCasualSyncFunction() (which isn't async itself) returns?

Comment: Redux thunk just allows you to so asynchronous stuff in your actions. It doesn't make async actions synchronous or anything like that. So now `doStuffAfterRandomCasualSyncFunctionReturns` will not wait for `randomCasualSyncFunction`

Comment: Thats what I know, but what happens in opposite way - if randomCasualSyncFunction is synchronous, will it finish before doStuffAfterRandomCasualSyncFunctionReturns()?

Comment: Yes by default `dispatch` itself is 100% synchronous, so assuming you're dispatching something that's also synchronous then it will all be finished by the time the next code runs

Comment: Thank you! So its the same as normal redux. Sometimes I wonder whats the point of having thunks, if you could just pass dispatch manually (because rest is the same)

Comment: So thunk is so you can have asynchronous stuff *inside* your action. As I said, by default `dispatch` is synchronous so any async stuff in the action you dispatch is lost. `redux-thunk` lets you do async stuff in an action and then still change the store with the async response/result